# Connect Canon Camera to Android via WiFi

Tags: android, camera, wifi

I got an old Canon PS 3500 IS, camera

It always connected well via WiFi to my Samsung GN3 Android through Canon Camera Connect app. It showed 4 rows of pictures and I could select <= 50 pics for download.

Now it only shows two rows of pics and all goes in slow motion, fading in each picture. (Still using Camera Connect app, I don't know why it changed behavior. I don't know if it updated for the worse.)

I always connect directly to the phone by setting the camera as an access point.

(In the meantime I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Canon Camera Window app which I believe is unrelated)

The version is
2.0.10.25  build 437

How do I get back the quick efficient picture transfer via WiFi?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a WiFi enabled DSLR – but you're welcome to check my list of [Camera remote control](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_tools#group_225) apps. Maybe there's some other app doing a better job.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. My camera is not DSLR, it is just a simple compact camera, but I like it and I have used it a lot. / It can not be controlled remotely, just download pictures.

Comment: Not being a DSLR might be limiting features – but basic stuff like photo preview and download might still work. Worth a try at least. // BTW: I'm just updating the linked list, so if you didn't find anything now it might be worth to check again in a few hours :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for keeping the list. / I don't know what happened. Suddenly very slow, interface also changed. I uninstalled Camera Window, but that is unrelated. I reinstalled it now. / I fear they updated Camera Connect to something my old camera dislikes :)

Comment: Afraid you might be right, there was an update on January 4th. One of the reasons I don't use auto-update (I always check the changelog first). You could try restoring a backup if you have one – or get the APK of the previous version to give it a try (see e.g. [APKPure](https://apkpure.com/))

Comment: Thanks. I found  [apk mirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/canon-inc/canon-camera-connect/canon-camera-connect-1-3-10-21-release/canon-camera-connect-1-3-10-21-android-apk-download/) but I don't understand how it works yet, the download "disappeared". I guess I must also start approving all updates manually, and not this one.

Comment: I got further with the site you gave. The app downloaded but when I try to install it, the phone trues a while and then says "app not installed". I have checked "allow unknown sources".

Comment: May I suggest you carry the install issue over to our [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) sister site, as that's off-topic here? But before asking, check [these posts](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q="app+not+installed"+answers%3A1) (you're obviously not the first with that issue). My guess is you first need to uninstall it (downgrade not allowed).

Comment: Thank you. Sounds like a good procedure. Time to sleep in my timezone. I will continue later. Thanks for constructive suggestions.